# How to deal with browser cache in Angular?

Tags: angular, caching, browser, refresh

the application takes value from the database and sends an API request with that value as a parameter. When new value is added to the database, and another API request is send, the app takes previous value as a parameter, and not the latest one in the database. It only takes the latest value after I refresh the browser. How to deal with this in Angular?

Is it related to browser cache?

App is using async promises, if that matters, and is in development mode, not deployed to production. Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're describing, where the app uses the previous value from the database even after a new value is added, and only reflects the latest value after refreshing the browser, is likely related to browser caching. In development mode, Angular's built-in caching mechanisms can sometimes cause data inconsistencies when making API requests.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    return this.http.get('/api/your_endpoint', { headers, cache: false });
  }
}
```

If you want to leverage caching in certain parts of your application but not others, you can use the cache option in the `HttpClient`.
By setting `cache: false`, you ensure that this specific request won't be cached, even if caching is enabled for other requests.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. It will serve me for sure, in various scenarios. I will add an answer to what actually was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After one day of debugging, I came to an understanding that this issue was not at all related to caching, even though it seemed that way because of how the application behaved.

The problem was inappropriately written SQL query. It was written in a way to return last record from the table that has a specific valueID attribute. But this valueID would be inserted in the database some time after the API request, so everytime I would make another request, then the valueID would exist and it would seem that the application is taking previous value, when in fact it was just doing what the query was telling it to.

After I adjusted the SQL query, I had no false behavior anymore :)

Debugging to the rescue!